# Unable to set onclick in AJAX loaded table

Tags: javascript, ajax

Actually in my website i'm building a timeline from AJAX and i was trying to set the onclick on each table row.

I was using class selector but the effect was nothing.
I actually read in another stackoverflow post that i had to set onclick on the closest static item but nothing.

So i've tryed

```
$(".timeline").on("click","table-row",function () { alert("we") ;});
```

and

```
$(".table-row").click(function () { alert("we"); });
```

Actually AJAX code where i create the timeline is the following

```
function createTavoli(salaSelect) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/getTavoli",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            data = r.d;
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            var count = 0;
            var time = [];
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var tabs = [];
                var numtav = item.NUM_TAV;
                var desctav = item.DESC_T;
                var coperti = item.COPERTI;
                var sala = item.SALA;


                if (sala == salaSelect) {
                    tabs.push('<tr id="' + numtav + '" data-salatav="' + sala + '" class="table-row">');
                    if (desctav != "") {
                        tabs.push('<th scope="row" class="noselect row-head text-left">' + desctav + '<span class="badge badge-dark ml-1">' + coperti + '</span></th>');
                    } else {
                        tabs.push('<th scope="row" class="noselect row-head text-left">' + "T. " + numtav + '<span class="badge badge-dark ml-1">' + coperti + '</span></th>');
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i <= 95 - Range; i++) {
                        tabs.push('<td style="padding: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 1;"></td>');
                    }
                    tabs.push('</tr>');
                    count++;
                    $('#timeline').append(tabs.join(""));
                }
                });

            time.push('<th scope="col" style="padding: 0px; border: 0; width: 80px;" class="row-head"></th>');
            for (var i = PartenzaOra; i <= 23; i++) {
                time.push('<th style="padding: 0px; border: 0; z-index: 3;" scope="colgroup" colspan="4"><p class="h noselect">' + ('0' + i).slice(-2) + '</p></th>');
            }
            $('#timehead').append(time.join(""));
            $('#counttav').text(count);
            getTavoli(new Date());
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrow) {
            alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

So which could be the best method to set onclick on the table-row class?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1s8tmk2a/) of how's build the timeline

Comment: $("#timeline").on("click",".table-row",function () {
    alert("we");
}); U intended this?

Comment: The problem you are facing is because the dynamically created elements are not bind to the event. Since Ajax code is creating a dynamic content, your on click event is not binding. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set click event after rows pushed to table. So put your `$(".table-row").click(function () { alert("we"); });` code to end of success function.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried

```
$(document).on("click", ".timeline .table-row" , function() {
  alert("we");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
$('body').on("click", ".table-row" , function() {
    alert("we");
});
```